# using $(this) to get data attribute doesnt return the actual result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to javascript/jquery, I've been searching all over the web but haven't got a satisfying answer. (I will delete it if someone can point out a similar question)

In the hmtl I have

```
<a href="#" class='btn-place-order' data-clicked=false data-confirm-modal="myModal">Submit</a>
```

In the console, I tried this

```
$('.btn-place-order').data("confirm-modal")
```

--> it returned "myModal"

But when I tried

```
$(".btn-place-order").on("click", function(e){ $(this).data("confirm-modal"); });
```

--> it return the whole object [a.btn-place-order]

Why ?

Comment: Your event handler does not do anything at all. It just accesses the value of the "data" attribute but then does nothing with it. Generally, no event handler should/can **return** anything.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: @Sergio not necessary in HTML5 documents.

Comment: Did you use `console.log()` ?. Like `$(".btn-place-order").on("click", function(e){ console.log($(this).data("confirm-modal")); });`

Comment: Try $(this).attr("confirm-modal")      The code you wrote returns the element this. Using attr will get that elements property

Comment: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6BuF4/ working as usual, rest I reckon most of the above comments you have read anyways, have a nice one `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is exactly correct.  If you take a look at the jQuery documentation you will see:

[jQuery `on`:](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
>   Returns: jQuery

[jQuery `data`:](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

> .data( key )
>   Returns: Object

This means that when you call `var myObject = $('.btn-place-order').data("confirm-modal");` will contain the value of the `data-` attribute.

However, when you call `$(".btn-place-order").on("click", function(e){ $(this).data("confirm-modal"); });` you get a jQuery object returned. This jQuery object is the same one that `$(".btn-place-order")` already returns, which is very important to make jQuery's concept of `chaining` work.

Chaining allows you to execute several methods in order, without getting the original jQuery object over and over.  For example `$(".btn-place-order").on('click',...).on('hover',...);` would allow you to attach two handlers (a `click` and a `hover`) to the same element.

It also wouldn't make sense for `on` to return anything else, since it just attaches a handler to an element.  It really doesn't give you any value just because you attach an event handler.

Now, if you want to take any action when the event is fired, you will need to take that action inside of the handler's `callback` function.  E.g.

```
$(".btn-place-order").on("click", function(e){ alert($(this).data("confirm-modal");) });
```

will alert the user of the `data-confirm-modal` attribute value of the element that was clicked on.  However, without the `alert()` part (i.e. the way your original code was written), the value is just read, but nothing is ever done with it.